# attempt to little design pattern in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

i'm learning c++. i know quite well java and python, but i'm getting mad in using a little design pattern fancy in my c++ trials.

here are my files, i think that they are quite auto-explicative, if there are some question, comment are welcome!

i have a class Engine that has a Behaviour.. i want to sublass Behaviour into different specific behaviours.. but it's quite easy also without subclass..

main.cpp :

```
#include "Engine.h"

int main() {
    Engine e;
    e.work();
    return 0;
};
```

Engine.h :

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H_
#define ENGINE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Behaviour.h"

class Engine {

public:

    Engine() {
        std::cout << "Engine constructor" << std::endl;
        this->b = new Behaviour(this);
    };
    virtual ~Engine(){};

    void work() {
        std::cout << "Engine work" << std::endl;
    };

    int getFoo() { return 42; };

private:
    Behaviour * b;
};

#endif /*  ENGINE_H_ */
```

Behaviour.h :

```
#ifndef BEHAVIOUR_H_
#define BEHAVIOUR_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Engine.h"

class Behaviour {

public:

    Behaviour(Engine* e) {
        std::cout << "behaviour constructor, kind of abstract class" << std::endl;
        this->e = e;
    };

    virtual ~Behaviour(){};

    void work() {
        std::cout << "Behaviour work" << this->e->getFoo() << std::endl;
    };

protected:
    Engine * e;

};

#endif /*  BEHAVIOUR_H_ */
```

my compiler errors:

```
$ rm *.gch; c++ *
In file included from Behaviour.h:5:
Engine.h:26: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Behaviour’ with no type
Engine.h:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Engine.h: In constructor ‘Engine::Engine()’:
Engine.h:14: error: ‘class Engine’ has no member named ‘b’
Engine.h:14: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Behaviour’
Engine.h:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘Behaviour’
In file included from Engine.h:5:
Behaviour.h:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Behaviour.h:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Engine’ with no type
Behaviour.h:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Behaviour.h: In member function ‘void Behaviour::work()’:
Behaviour.h:19: error: ‘class Behaviour’ has no member named ‘e’
Engine.h: In constructor ‘Engine::Engine()’:
Engine.h:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘Behaviour::Behaviour(Engine* const)’
Behaviour.h:7: note: candidates are: Behaviour::Behaviour()
Behaviour.h:7: note:                 Behaviour::Behaviour(const Behaviour&)
```

i think i need some forward declarations but i'm not sure and looking through tutorials and make some trials does not resolve my problems at all.

Comment: Does this pattern *really* require that `Engine` have a pointer to `Behaviour` and vice versa?

Comment: I was about to mention the same as @juanchopanza Actually its not a very nice design to have this sort of cross-dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Engine.h` replace the include with a forward declaration:

```
#include "Behaviour.h"
```

with

```
class Behaviour;
```

Same for `class Engine;` inside `Behavior.h`.

Because you have a cyclic dependency, you'll need to use forward declarations instead of includes.

**You'll also need to separate the implementation in a `cpp` file.** A forward declaration alone won't let you call `this->b = new Behaviour(this);`.

Also, take some time to rethink your design. This sort of dependancy is usually a code smell.

Comment: Engine contains a render engine and behaviours need to render into the gui. something like: engine.drawString("blabla"). some advice?

Comment: @nkint, use dependency injection to inject (from the engine) into the Behavior what it needs from the Engine, as opposed to the entire Engine itself.

Comment: by the way, i get this error: Behaviour.cpp:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Engine’
Behaviour.h:6: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Engine’

Comment: @nkint: In bold in the answer **You'll also need to separate the implementation in a cpp file.**

Answer (score 1):

You got a cyclic dependency problem, usually, you have to implement Behaviour's method in a CPP file, but it might not the best practice.
I think the Engine is a very important abstract concept in your application, you can describe it with a pure virtual class as a interface definition.

For example:

IEngine.h

```
class IEngine {
public:
    void work() = 0;
};

IEngine* newEngine();
```

EngineImpl.h

```
class EngineImpl : public IEngine {
public:
    void work();
};
```

EngineImpl.cpp

```
void EngineImpl::work();
   // do some works
}

IEngine* newEngine() {
    return new EngineImpl();
}
```

Now, you can use your engine by IEngine anywhere in your code just by include IEngine.h. and you can even impl an Engine singleton by define:

IEngine.h:

```
IEngine* sharedEngine();
```

EngineImpl.cpp

```
IEngine* sharedEngine() {
    static IEngine *engineInst = 0;
    if (!engineInst)
        engineInst = new EngineImpl();
    return engineInst; 
}
```